# How does this work? Data catching without displaying client

Tags: c#, bots

Alright so this is about a game, but more generally this can probably be done for all games, I just want to figure out how the application accomplishes it.

So it's for a game called League of Legends, huge game, has an executable file and a massive LoLClient where you can view all data specific to your account, you can queue for games etc.

Now what this app does (that I've came across) is it logs into the league client, grabs all info related to the character and logs out) but it does this without even displaying the client on the users screen, how is this possible? bare in mind it isn't using a server.

A broad question perhaps, but I'm sure there's a straightforward question (app developed in C#)

Answer (score 0):

Riot has a Json API for devs to use and poll their servers for information they need to create websites and applications. It's not even touching the client; if it is, the dev of the app is either a little slow or scraping more than just 'champion information'.

In general if an application from an untrusted source is asking for login credentials, do some research and figure out why - after that use your best judgement. With that said, in most cases, if it is asking for such things and you didn't create any to use with that application itself, it's probably not a good idea.

If it is asking for **authentication** from a known good source (twitter, fb, google apis for eg) then make sure you check which permissions it's asking for **before** authorizing it to use your account. In some cases, it's just as good as giving them your username and password - the only difference being generally you can remove the authentication if weird behaviour starts up.

[Riots API](https://developer.riotgames.com/)

Comment: Riot doesn't have anything in the API that allows devs to take credentials, log in with those credentials then stick the user in queue for a game. This seems to be done without the riot api

Comment: That's not what you said this app does. You said and I quote "it logs into the league client, grabs all info related to the character and logs out". That has nothing to do with creds (client side anyway) it's to do with the api and riot would likely to be using their own api to display the information in their client. As for the login credentials I'm speaking in generalities - I'm saying if you come across an application that asks for any login credentials that you didn't create for use with the app, its not a good idea give them yours. Plus, using apis that ask for permissions can be like

Comment: Giving them the username and password anyway. I'm saying be careful. Don't trust anybody unless they're known to be trustworthy, and even then don't be afraid to ask questions. Have a good one